# Read specific pattern in C from standard in

Tags: c, scanf

I am having trouble reading some standard input on a console application in C.

I need to get the input in a specific pattern/format such as '(num, num)' without the quotes. That being [[ open parenthesys, a number, a comma, a space, another number, closing parenthesys ]].

When I had my program read with `scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);` it would read two numbers separated by a space. I want to try and make it understand the desired pattern as described above such as `scanf("(%d, %d)", &a, &b);` where a is the first number and b is the second. This does not work as after this scanf, I also have another input prompt which gets skipped due to the string pattern but works with `scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);`. Any advice?

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

  int a, b, c;

  printf("This is where the pait is required: ");
  scanf("(%d, %d)", &a, &b);

  printf("a: %d, b: %d\n", a, b); // Check values here...

  printf("This is where I ask for another number as input: ");
  scanf("%d", &c);

  printf("c: %d\n", c); // Check value here...

  // Do stuff here but above code should skip over the second scanf...

  exit(0);
}
```

Comment: `scanf("(%d, %d)", &a, &b);` Have you tried it, and what did not work?

Comment: @dxiv So after I do that, I have another input (will edit that into the question). When I press the Return key, it will take the two numbers but will also skip the next input giving me a run-time error.

Comment: "I also have another input prompt which gets skipped". Please show the code as a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: ```
printf(This is where the pait is required: ");
scanf("(%d, %d)", &a, &b);

printf("This is where I ask for another number as input: ");
scanf("%d", &c);

// Do irrelevant stuff here...

```

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61669046/edit) your question to add the complete code (not in comments). Please note that "complete" means code that someone else can take exactly as is to build, run and reproduce the problem.

Comment: Added some minimal code that I would like to be tested and checked against. Thank you.

Comment: @MariosYiannakou The code you just edited in (a) doesn't compile as posted, and (b) after the missing quote is fixed, it does in fact work. Please post the *real* code.

Comment: I have tested this and you are correct, alone this code would work. I figured out it was a newline character error. Something is being read extra or less. I have fixed this by setting my scanf as _scanf("(%d, %d)\n", &a, &b);_ and a _getchar();_ after any previous _scanf()_ in the code.

Comment: It's safer to just use `" (%d ,%d )"` in both places, with no `getchar` needed.

Comment: @dxiv is the space at the beginning and end intentional?

Comment: @dxiv Okay I think I understand now, the space is supposed to 'absorb' the Return key and spaces?

Comment: @MariosYiannakou Right. Also note that `%d` 'absorbs' any leading whitespace, so the format would read `(123,456)` with any number of spaces or newlines inserted between the numbers and delimiters.

Comment: Amazing! Just what I needed thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by @dxiv
"It's safer to just use `" (%d ,%d )"` in both places, with no getchar needed"
"Also note that %d 'absorbs' any leading whitespace, so the format would read `(123,456)` with any number of spaces or newlines inserted between the numbers and delimiters."